# does one have to keep stock until the dividend payment date to get the dividend? (Record Date vs Payment Date)

Tags: stocks, dividends

For example: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/atvi/dividend-history has a dividend record date 3/30/2015 and a payment date of 5/13/2015. When one sells the stock now, past record date, but before payment date, will one still get the dividend?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to hold the shares at the opening of the ex-dividend date to get the dividends. So you can actually sell the shares on ex-dividend date and still get the dividends.

Ex-dividend date occurs before the record date and payment date, so you will get the dividend even if you sold before the record date.